# Getting stdout using vscode mingw gcc

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I wanted to extent my c knowledge to c++. Using Win10, I installed VSCode and mingw following the tutorials.

Next I created a Hello World test file.
It compiles properly without errors. However when I run it from a terminal window, I do not get any output.
I am sure its a stupid beginners mistake...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello Moon!";
    std::cout.flush();
    return 0;
}
```

compiling:

```
Kompilierung wird gestartet...
D:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g3 -Wall "D:\CPLUSPLUS\programs\hello world\hello world.cpp" -o "D:\CPLUSPLUS\programs\hello world\hello world.exe"

Die Kompilierung wurde erfolgreich abgeschlossen.
```

console:

```
PS D:\CPLUSPLUS\programs\hello world> "hello world.exe"
hello world.exe
PS D:\CPLUSPLUS\programs\hello world>
```

so obviously it runs the exe without complaint, however I do not see any output...

Any hints/ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it runs the exe instead of printing the `"hello world.exe"` string to the console cause that is what powershell does to strings?

Comment: As a general rule, avoid `using namespace` in favor of `using` individual identifiers, e.g. `using std::cout` (and then just use `cout` without the `std::` prefix).

Comment: I vaguely remember that some mingw64 gcc builds just don't work properly. I don't have a windows computer handy to verify this. You may want to try running your program from the msys console rather than from the PS console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks quimby! that did the job!

actually ist not my c++ vscode ignorance but the one of powershell (coming from cmd...)

so you are right: powershell did NOT run my program but rather just echo the quoted string.

so ones needs the & operator to do the job.

Problem solved
Thanks again.

Comment: You can accept your own answer so that it shows at the top for others searching for the solution.

Answer (score -2):

i guess you need to remove the std:: prefix because you already imported the std

try this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Hello Moon!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see what difference this should make, if there aren't any compiler errors? Don't post guesses as answers here, unless you're sure.

Comment: This does not address the OP question. It does also not resolve any error in the code. If at all, need to mention that `using namespace` is not the way to go.